# Flutter Firebase Messaging Deactivate Visible Notification

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I deactivate the visible notification in Firebase Messaging and handle the notification manually with the flutter_local_notifications package so the notification doesn't show twice? I'm not able to edit the server integration side since am I using a wordpress plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/fcm-push-notification-from-wp/) to send a notification request for me.

The payload looks like this: https://ps.w.org/fcm-push-notification-from-wp/assets/screenshot-6.png?rev=2446404

```
String selectedNotificationPayload = "";
final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
final BehaviorSubject<String> selectNotificationSubject =
    BehaviorSubject<String>();
FirebaseMessaging messaging;

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('share_icon');

  final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
      IOSInitializationSettings(
          requestSoundPermission: false,
          requestBadgePermission: false,
          requestAlertPermission: false,
          onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
              (int id, String title, String body, String payload) async {});

  final InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
    iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
  );

  NotificationAppLaunchDetails notificationAppLaunchDetails =
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
  if (notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false) {
    selectedNotificationPayload = notificationAppLaunchDetails.payload;
  }

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: (String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      selectedNotificationPayload = payload;
      selectNotificationSubject.add(payload);
    }
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(Start());
}
```

```
class Start extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StartState createState() => _StartState();
}

class _StartState extends State<Start>{
  void initializeFlutterFire() async {
    try {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      print("Firebase - initialzed successfully");
    } catch (e) {
      print("Firebase - initialzed FAILED");
    }
    messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  }

  void _configureSelectNotificationSubject() async {
    selectNotificationSubject.stream.listen((String _url) async {
      try {
        await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), () async {
          await Navigator.of(context).push(new Route(_url, ""));
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print("Fehler beim öffnen der Website");
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    initializeFlutterFire();
  }

...

}
```

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  Map<String, dynamic> data = message.data;

  String _title = data['title'];
  String _description = data['message'];

  sendNotification(_title, _description);
}
```

Comment: send only data payload

Comment: I can't change what is being sent to the device, is there a way to do it within the app?